# Excel: Calculate week of fiscal year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, week-number

I am trying to calculate the week number of the fiscal year that a given date falls on - our fiscal year begins on July 1 and ends June 30, weeks go from Sun-Sat and the data contain multiple years.

For example: 7/1/2017 falls on a Saturday, so it would be week 1 in the fiscal year. 7/2-7/8, 2017 would be week 2 and the week of 6/23-6/30, 2018 would be week 52, this would start over to week 1 on 7/1/2018.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Screenshot of data I'm working with

[image]

Screenshot of formulas in Weekday, FiscalYear, and FiscalQuarter]

[image]

Comment: If July 1st falls on a Sunday, is it day #1 of week #1 of the following year?  Or is the following Sunday day #1 ??

Comment: clearly if we can determine day#1/week#1 we can calculate the difference from a given date mod 7 *(nicht wahr?)*

Comment: I would love it if you used ISO 8601 date formats (i.e. yyyy/MM/dd). Less than 5% of the world uses the `M/d/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the others, I understand you to mean that the fiscal year always starts on July 1, and that the week changes on Sunday.

**Algorithm**

- Compute preceding July 1: `=DATE(YEAR(A2)-IF(MONTH(A2)>=7,0,1),7,1)`
- Compute first Sunday of the fiscal year:  `=prevJul1 +7-WEEKDAY(prevJul1 +6)`
- Compute weeknumber since first Sunday: `=INT((A2-firstSunday)/7)+1`
- Add `1` if `prevJul1` is not a Sunday

Putting it all together:

```
=INT((A2-(DATE(YEAR(A2)-IF(MONTH(A2)>=7,0,1),7,1)+7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2)-IF(MONTH(A2)>=7,0,1),7,1)+6)))/7)+1+(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2)-IF(MONTH(A2)>=7,0,1),7,1))<>1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you nailed it.  I did not realize the week #1 could be "short".

Answer (score 0):

Computes the week number for any date where week 1 starts on the first Sunday on or after the 1st of July:

```
=INT(([@Date]-(DATE(YEAR([@Date]-WEEKDAY([@Date])+1)-IF(MONTH([@Date]-WEEKDAY([@Date])+1)>=7,0,1),7,1)+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([@Date]-WEEKDAY([@Date])+1)-IF(MONTH([@Date]-WEEKDAY([@Date])+1)>=7,0,1),7,1)),7)))/7)+1
```

Here's some sample output:

```
Date           | WeekNo
-------------- | ------
2017/06/17 Sat | 50    
2017/06/18 Sun | 51    
2017/06/19 Mon | 51    
2017/06/20 Tue | 51    
2017/06/21 Wed | 51    
2017/06/22 Thu | 51    
2017/06/23 Fri | 51    
2017/06/24 Sat | 51    
2017/06/25 Sun | 52    
2017/06/26 Mon | 52    
2017/06/27 Tue | 52    
2017/06/28 Wed | 52    
2017/06/29 Thu | 52    
2017/06/30 Fri | 52    
2017/07/01 Sat | 52    
2017/07/02 Sun | 1     
2017/07/03 Mon | 1     
2017/07/04 Tue | 1     
2017/07/05 Wed | 1     
2017/07/06 Thu | 1     
2017/07/07 Fri | 1     
2017/07/08 Sat | 1     
2017/07/09 Sun | 2     
2018/06/17 Sun | 51    
2018/06/18 Mon | 51    
2018/06/19 Tue | 51    
2018/06/20 Wed | 51    
2018/06/21 Thu | 51    
2018/06/22 Fri | 51    
2018/06/23 Sat | 51    
2018/06/24 Sun | 52    
2018/06/25 Mon | 52    
2018/06/26 Tue | 52    
2018/06/27 Wed | 52    
2018/06/28 Thu | 52    
2018/06/29 Fri | 52    
2018/06/30 Sat | 52    
2018/07/01 Sun | 1     
2018/07/02 Mon | 1     
2018/07/03 Tue | 1     
2018/07/04 Wed | 1     
2018/07/05 Thu | 1     
2018/07/06 Fri | 1     
2018/07/07 Sat | 1     
2018/07/08 Sun | 2     
2018/07/09 Mon | 2     
2019/06/17 Mon | 51    
2019/06/18 Tue | 51    
2019/06/19 Wed | 51    
2019/06/20 Thu | 51    
2019/06/21 Fri | 51    
2019/06/22 Sat | 51    
2019/06/23 Sun | 52    
2019/06/24 Mon | 52    
2019/06/25 Tue | 52    
2019/06/26 Wed | 52    
2019/06/27 Thu | 52    
2019/06/28 Fri | 52    
2019/06/29 Sat | 52    
2019/06/30 Sun | 53    
2019/07/01 Mon | 53    
2019/07/02 Tue | 53    
2019/07/03 Wed | 53    
2019/07/04 Thu | 53    
2019/07/05 Fri | 53    
2019/07/06 Sat | 53    
2019/07/07 Sun | 1     
2019/07/08 Mon | 1     
2019/07/09 Tue | 1     
2020/06/17 Wed | 50    
2020/06/18 Thu | 50    
2020/06/19 Fri | 50    
2020/06/20 Sat | 50    
2020/06/21 Sun | 51    
2020/06/22 Mon | 51    
2020/06/23 Tue | 51    
2020/06/24 Wed | 51    
2020/06/25 Thu | 51    
2020/06/26 Fri | 51    
2020/06/27 Sat | 51    
2020/06/28 Sun | 52    
2020/06/29 Mon | 52    
2020/06/30 Tue | 52    
2020/07/01 Wed | 52    
2020/07/02 Thu | 52    
2020/07/03 Fri | 52    
2020/07/04 Sat | 52    
2020/07/05 Sun | 1     
2020/07/06 Mon | 1     
2020/07/07 Tue | 1     
2020/07/08 Wed | 1     
2020/07/09 Thu | 1     
2021/06/17 Thu | 50    
2021/06/18 Fri | 50    
2021/06/19 Sat | 50    
2021/06/20 Sun | 51    
2021/06/21 Mon | 51    
2021/06/22 Tue | 51    
2021/06/23 Wed | 51    
2021/06/24 Thu | 51    
2021/06/25 Fri | 51    
2021/06/26 Sat | 51    
2021/06/27 Sun | 52    
2021/06/28 Mon | 52    
2021/06/29 Tue | 52    
2021/06/30 Wed | 52    
2021/07/01 Thu | 52    
2021/07/02 Fri | 52    
2021/07/03 Sat | 52    
2021/07/04 Sun | 1     
2021/07/05 Mon | 1     
2021/07/06 Tue | 1     
2021/07/07 Wed | 1     
2021/07/08 Thu | 1     
2021/07/09 Fri | 1     
2022/06/17 Fri | 50    
2022/06/18 Sat | 50    
2022/06/19 Sun | 51    
2022/06/20 Mon | 51    
2022/06/21 Tue | 51    
2022/06/22 Wed | 51    
2022/06/23 Thu | 51    
2022/06/24 Fri | 51    
2022/06/25 Sat | 51    
2022/06/26 Sun | 52    
2022/06/27 Mon | 52    
2022/06/28 Tue | 52    
2022/06/29 Wed | 52    
2022/06/30 Thu | 52    
2022/07/01 Fri | 52    
2022/07/02 Sat | 52    
2022/07/03 Sun | 1     
2022/07/04 Mon | 1     
2022/07/05 Tue | 1     
2022/07/06 Wed | 1     
2022/07/07 Thu | 1     
2022/07/08 Fri | 1     
2022/07/09 Sat | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If **A1** contains July 1<sup>st</sup> of any year, then **B1**:

```
=A1+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A1),0,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

will give the date of the first Sunday after or on that date.  This is day #1 of week #1 of the new fiscal year

Now it is easy to get the week number:

```
=INT(1+(date_in_question - day#1week#1)/7)
```

Copy **B1** and PasteSpecialValues and formats into **C1**

**C1** is the starting date of the new fiscal year

In **D1** put an arbitrary date within the new fiscal year.  In **E1** enter:

```
=INT(1+(D1-C1)/7)
```

[image]